# Firebase Database Rules about

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm using firebase database to keep logs , That's why I need to keep permissions open.

but it starts to send google security emails every day every day. If I turn off permissions, they can't log

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write":true
  }
}
```

That's why I want to keep it open so that data can be read and written from my mobile application, but you can't make a scarf.

How can I make these settings? Is it possible?

Comment: What are you using to write and read from your database? Are you logged in using Firebase Authentication in that?

Comment: If all you need is logging, Realtime Database is not your best solution for that.  The security emails are suggesting to you that anyone can easily read and write your entire database at will.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable Firebase Authentication in your Android app, you can change the rules so that only signed in users are able to read/write data:

```
{
  rules": {
    ".read": auth.uid != null,
    ".write": auth.uid != null
  }
}
```

You can learn more about Firebase Database rules here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

And adding Firebase Authentication here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth

Comment: Thank you, this will solve my job, I examine the document immediately,
I'd like to vote for you but I don't have enough points :(

Comment: this way my problem was solved thanks
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}